# Server-Sent Events on Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-sent-events

I'm actually trying to create a web-application which will utilizes the [Server-Sent Events draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/). From my knowledge, SSEs utilize one thread per connection, and since the server is going to continuously pump data to the client, without being idle even for a second, there's no way I'll be able to put the thread back in the pool.

Hence I'm trying to use Node.JS (which I haven't used till date) to handle connections to the server. I've been through the [HTML5 Rocks introduction to SSE](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) and there is a code sample integrating SSEs with Node.JS.

However, I'm confused as to whether Node.JS will handle the thousands of client connections concurrently and **utilize the server more efficiently than an Apache server**? Can anyone help me understand how exactly Node will act here?

Sorry if I sound a bit too vague. I'm ready to make as many clarifications as possible! Thanks!

Comment: if you haven't, watch this intro video (yes it's long, but it's good) http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/20/video-dahl/

Comment: you know that IE and FF are a no-go for this method right?

Comment: @generalhenry - Thanks for the link. Will check it out.

Comment: @billy-moon - Yes, I'm thinking of resorting to Node.JS + Socket.Io for browsers other than Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 4):

php:

```
do {
  sendMsg($startedAt , time());
  sleep(5);
} while(true);
```

vs

node.js

```
setInterval(function() {
  constructSSE(res, id, (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString());
}, 5000);
```

The difference it the sleep blocks the php thread 5 seconds.  During those 5 seconds the server needs to have a dedicated thread doing absolutely nothing.  One thread per user.

With the node.js version the setInterval doesn't block the thread.  The one node.js thread can handle all the users.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up with your last sentence. That's what I was looking for. So if I were to optimize this handling further and say make Node.JS handle 20k+ concurrent connections, what would I have to do? Maybe I should ask that as a separate section

Comment: the key is making sure node isn't being gummed up with calculations, one bad while loop will gum up the works.

Answer (score 3):

Try to look at [Understanding the node.js event loop](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/) article regarding concurrent connections. I would recommend to create a web application which utilizes WebSockets rather then Server-sent events because SSEs are less supported by browsers than WebSockets. Also there are lots of WebSockets based node.js modules with source codes at GitHub which can "inspire" you.

Comment: That and socket.io makes it easy to not care what transport the browser supports since it can emulate sockets even in ie6

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I was thinking more on the lines of Server-Sent Events saving valuable bandwidth since it's only accepting one request and after that continuously pushing out data.

Answer (score 2):

> However, I'm confused as to whether
>   Node.JS will handle the thousands of
>   client connections concurrently and
>   utilize the server more efficiently
>   than an Apache server? Can anyone help
>   me understand how exactly Node will
>   act here?

I think you should read [Understanding event loops and writing great code for Node.js](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/understanding-the-event-loops-and-writing-great-code-for-node-js-part-1/) to get a better grasp about the event-loop. In node.js nothing is blocking which will save you tons of CPU-cycles.

Also [TJ's ebook](http://visionmedia.github.com/masteringnode/) can help you grasp events. When something happens your callback associated with that event will be called.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. However, when I'm using Node.JS to deliver Server-Sent Events, do I need to write some explicit piping code into Node.JS or will it do this automatically to an extent?

Comment: You should probably use datastore(redis) to store your messages. The pubsub semnantics from redis are also very powerful. I would also advice you to have a look at socket.io which is also very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express) + [connect-sse](https://github.com/superjoe30/connect-sse):

```
var sse, express, app;

sse = require('connect-sse')();
express = require('express')

app = express()
app.get('/events', sse, function (req, res) {
  res.json("this is an event");
  res.json({here: "is", another: "event"});
});
```